# Test projects do not run in one solution within Visual Studio 2019 but they run in another

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2019

I noticed a very weird change, lately, in one of our solutions in Visual Studio 2019. Two test projects are included in more than one solution. However, in ONE of the solutions ONLY, both of the test projects do not run anymore. It seems like they are not recognized as test projects within Visual Studio 2019.

***How could the SAME test projects run in one solution but do not in another?*** It is very weird as behavior. The packages and references are tied to the projects not to the solutions.

All the test projects reference these two references:

**Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions**

If I replace these, two references, by that one

**Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework**

then these two test projects are running again.

To switch the newer namespace back to the older namespace is not a reason enough, I think.

Thank you very much for your help, Mimi

Comment: Can you give more details about what you mean by "do not run"?  Do they not show up in the Test Explorer window?  Or if they do, does running them provide any messages in the Output Window for Tests?

Comment: In the Test Explorer window, the tests are there but marked with the blue exclamation point and Outcomes: 164 Not Run. In the Output Window, build is successful, but 0 tests succeeded, 0 Failed.

Comment: You can try turning up the verbosity for test output under Tools -> Options -> Test -> General -> Logging Level and see if that gives more details about why it's not running.  This sounds like an issue to take up with the product team though at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/